# Internet disables after internal Wi-Fi  transfer

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, wan

When I transfer a file, that is, drag and drop from my computer to another computer, the router loses connection to the Internet. The internal network is fine, but I have to reset the router to reconnect to the Internet. Why is it doing this?

Comment: Interesting. Can you be sure it's the router that's dropping the connection? In other words, are other computers on the network not able to get to the Internet either? What router is it?

Comment: Yes, I am sure its the router. All of my computers are unable to connect to the internet, but we can connect to each other. I have the linksys 54g wireless router ( yup ooooollllllddddd school)

Comment: Yeah, what Spiff said: replace your router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you just have buggy equipment. There's no good reason for that to happen. Make sure you have the latest firmware on your router and the latest wireless drivers on your computers.

If you have truly isolated the problem to the router, replace it with a higher quality router.

Comment: Thank you i'll keep this in mind, I have the linksys 54g wireless router, I was planing on doing the router firmware hack. Do you think this would help?

Comment: @Cjueden I don't have much experience with after-market third-party open-source firmware distributions for home gateway routers, so I can't advise you on that. However, the Linksys WRT54G was introduced in 2002. Trying to squeeze more life out of a decade-old design seems like a waste of time and effort. My usual advice is to buy a modern simultaneous dual-band N router.

Comment: I usually replace my routers every two years. My WRT54G was an exception to the rule. I owned it for three years.